# Glide 3.7.0 not loading images from URL

Tags: android, url, jpeg, android-glide

I am trying out Glide, because I hear it is awesome.  However I can't get any images to load from a URL.  Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.i58740.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my activity:

```
package com.example.i58740.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String imgUrl = "http://shirtoid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/A-French-Ninja-Cat.jpg";

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Finally I got both these dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

I've also add the internet permission in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have looked at several tutorials and some everything I've read this should work.  There are no errors or exceptions either.  The Url in the snippet above is valid.  I have also tried it with many other Urls I know to be valid, still nothing works.

Comment: do u have the internet permission on the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes, I added the internet permission and it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So I figure out the problem thanks to Budius's suggestion.  I doubled checked to make sure I had indeed added the internet permission and realized it was nested in the < application> tag.  Moving it outside of that fixed the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to see you manifest file so that one can see where you put the permissions.